# Text classification for data with multiple labels per observation

Tags: classification, text

I have a dataset of tweets that has been labeled by multiple people. So the columns look something like:

Tweet_ID, Coder_1_Classification, Coder_2_Classification, etc.

The idea is to build a tweet classifier based on the labels. How should I input this data into the classifier? I was thinking of taking the plurality response, but is there a way I can use all of the data?

Also, there is partial coverage, so not every labeler labeled every tweet.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/07/multi-label-classification-with-keras/) blog post about multi-label classification. Encode your labels using [Multi Label Binarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html), then you optimize binary crossentropy loss over sigmoid on those encoded labels.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options:

- Multi-class classification: each tweet can be labelled with several classes
- Majority voting: each tweet is labelled with the class chosen most often
- Consider tweets with (too many) different labels as ambiguous and remove them from the dataset
- ...

Additionally it's usually useful to calculate the [inter-annotator agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability), because this indicates how subjective the task is and therefore how accurate one can expect the predictions to be.